# c++ Eigen block diagonal matrix from dense vectors without copy

Tags: c++, reference, sparse-matrix, eigen

I have (dense and large) row vectors v_1, ..., v_D, and I need a matrix X to be block diagonal (whose i-th block is v_i), in order to perform matrix products like

```
X.transpose() * H.selfadjointView<Lower>() * X
```

That is, X should be sparse and its i-th row is v_i :

```
(pseudo code)
RowVectorXd v1(1,2,3), v2(4,5), v3(6,7,8,9);
SparseMatrix<double> X(3,9); 

// I need X to be
X = 1 2 3 . . . . . .
    . . . 4 5 . . . .
    . . . . . 6 7 8 9 

// where . means 0
```

**EDIT:** My question is: is it possible to do this product without actually forming X nor copying the v_i's, but simply using references to them? My concern is about performance and memory footprint.

I think the solution has something to do with Eigen::Map<...Stride...> but I can't get it.

Many thanks.

Comment: Your question would be easier for people to answer if you included a "minimal example" of at the type of matrix you wish to form and the code you tried that does use the copy.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've added the corresponding pseudo code.

Comment: You can't copy the vectors into the `SparseMatrix` without copying them (obviously ...). If your `SparseMatrix` has a pure dense block structure (i.e., no structural zeros inside the blocks), you can access these blocks using an `Eigen::Map` without copying them. Whether you actually need to construct your matrix `X` depends on what you intend to do with it.

Comment: @chtz That's exactly the point. I am wondering whether X should be formed? I edited my question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: I guess the question remains, what do you intend to do with `X^T*H*X`? It will consist of rank-1 subblocks (and explicitly storing rank-1 matrices is often a bad idea, especially if you knew the vectors to construct it). Also, is `H` sparse or dense?

Comment: My computations will end up storing the matrix resulting from X^THX+B where H and B are dense and symmetric matrices. H, B and the vectors building X are known, and I am wondering if there is a trick to get the dense matrix X^THX+B without storing X. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding an answer to my question. I post it here in case anyone else needs it. For this particular configuration of the matrix X, we can form directly

```
B = X^T * H * X
```

where X is as in the question and H is symmetric, without explicitly forming X. As X^T H X is symmetric, we only need to form the lower diagonal and use

```
B.selfadjointView<Lower>()
```

to call B.

Note that X^T H X is equivalent to H ** W, where W is the following lower triangular matrix with blocks being

```
W = v_1^T * v_1
    v_2^T * v_1    v_2^T * v_2
    .              .             v_3^T * v_3
    .              .             .               ...
    .              .             .               ...
    v_D^T * v_1    v_D^T * v_2   v_D^T * v_3     ...  v_D^T * v_D
```

and ** is an overloaded operator that computes the component-wise product between the (i,j) scalar of H and the block (i,j)  in W. So

```
B = H ** (v^T * v)
```